# How can I zoom with mouse scroll on WPF TrackballDecorator (3dTools)?

Tags: wpf, scroll, zooming, trackball

Currently I can zoom using right click. Is there a simple method to do it with mouse scroll ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(e);
            if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
            {
                yourObject.Value += (e.Delta > 0) ? 0.2 : -0.2;
            }
```